# Integral Encountered in Physics Problem

Tags: integration, physics

My question is technically just a math question that came up in the context of a physics problem. In particular, it came up in a  perturbation calculation for a two dimensional electron gas. Long story short, the integral is 
$$\int_{k'<k_F}\int_{k<k_F}\frac{d^2\mathbf{k}\,d^2\mathbf{k}'}{|\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{k}'|}$$
and I am not sure how to evaluate this. For clarity, these integrals are over the 2D Fermi Sphere (i.e., the  Fermi disk) with radius $k_F$.

---

For those curious of the physical context, the situation that this turned up in is a two-dimensional electron gas (not ignoring spin) with a $1/r$ two-body interaction. Writing the potential $V(\mathbf{r}_i-\mathbf{r}_j) = A/|\mathbf{r}_i-\mathbf{r}_j|$, it turns out that the interaction operator can be written in second quantized form as
$$
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i\neq j}V(\mathbf{r}_i-\mathbf{r}_j) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{\substack{\mathbf{k},\mathbf{k}',\mathbf{q} \\ s,s'}}V_\mathbf{q} c_{\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{q},s}^\dagger c_{\mathbf{k}'+\mathbf{q},s'}^\dagger c_{\mathbf{k'},s'}c_{\mathbf{k},s}
$$
where the $c$ and $c^\dagger$'s are the annihilation and creation operators for the state indicated in their subscript. The sum is over allowed momenta and spins. The matrix elements are
$$
V_\mathbf{q} = \frac{1}{\Omega}\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} V(\mathbf{r}) e^{i\mathbf{q}\cdot\mathbf{r}}\,d^2\mathbf{r} = \frac{2\pi A}{\Omega q}.
$$
where $\Omega$ is the area of the box containing the gas.

Ignoring the direct scattering term $\mathbf{q}=0$ (it is being compensated in a Jellium-like manner), we wish to evaluate the exchange ($\mathbf{q}=\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{k}'$) energy shift to the ground state 
$$
E_\text{ex} = \frac{\pi A}{\Omega}\sum \frac{1}{|\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{k}'|}
$$
where this sum proceeds only over the occupied states with same spin. Taking the continuum limit leads to the integral in question.

There are more details regarding the spin and an actual net magnetization, but they are irrelevant to the integral I need to solve.

I was originally going to post this on Physics Stackexchange, but I figured since it boils down to a math question, someone here might be able to help.

Thanks in advance for any advice you may be able to offer!

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question - but just to make sure, given the difference in math/physics languages:  your integral(s) has (have) $k'$ and $k$ range over the interior of the ball of radius $k_F$ centered at the origin in $\mathbb R^2$.  Is that correct? (The word 'circle' argues against this - but the $d^2k$ of the integral ...)

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I should have said disk. The integrals are both over a disk of radius $k_F$ centered at the origin. Fixed it, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $k = (r_1\cos\theta_1,r_1\sin\theta_1), k' = (r_2\cos\theta_2,r_2\sin\theta_2)$.

In physicist's convention, the integral we want to evaluate has the form:

$$\mathcal{I} \stackrel{def}{=}
\int_0^{k_F} r_1 d r_1
\int_0^{k_F}r_2 dr_2
\int_0^{2\pi} d\theta_1 
\int_0^{2\pi} d\theta_2
\frac{1}{
\sqrt{r_1^2+r_2^2 - 2r_1r_2\cos(\theta_2-\theta_1)}}
$$
Let 
$r = \max(r_1,r_2)$, $\displaystyle\;\lambda = \frac{\min(r_1,r_2)}{\max(r_1,r_2)}$, $\phi = \theta_2 - \theta_1 + \pi$. Let $x = \lambda\cos\phi$, $y = \lambda\sin\phi$.

Change variable from $r_1, r_2, \theta_1, \theta_2$ first to $r, \lambda, \theta_1, \phi$ and then to $r, \theta_1, x,y$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I} 
&= 2\int_0^{k_F} r dr \int_0^1 r^2\lambda d\lambda
\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta_1\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\frac{1}{r\sqrt{1+\lambda^2+2\lambda\cos\phi}}\\
&= 2\left(\int_0^{k_F}r^2dr\right)
\left(\int_0^{2\pi} d\theta_1\right)\int_0^1 \lambda d\lambda \int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\frac{1}{\sqrt{(\lambda\cos\phi + 1)^2 + (\lambda\sin\phi)^2}}\\
&= \frac{4\pi}{3}k_F^3\int_{x^2+y^2\le 1}\frac{dxdy}{\sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2}}
\end{align}
$$
Introduce "polar" coordinate $(\rho,\psi)$ centered at $(-1,0)$, i.e,
$(x,y) = (-1+\rho\cos\psi,\rho\sin\psi)$.
We can evaluate the integral in last line as

$$\int_{x^2+y^2\le 1}\frac{dxdy}{\sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2}}
= \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{2\cos\psi} \frac{\rho d\rho d\psi}{\rho}
= \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} 2\cos\psi d\psi = 4$$
As a result, $\displaystyle\;\mathcal{I} = \frac{16\pi}{3} k_F^3$.

Comment: And, in case some readers are confused: on the set $ \{r_1 < r_2\}$, $r = r_2$, and $r_1 = \lambda r$; on the set  $\{r_2 \le r_1\}$, the roles are reversed. Hence the leading factor of $2$ in ${\cal I } = 2\cdots$ above.

Comment: @peterag yup those are typos, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Also,again for clarity's sake: in the integral over $\phi$,  the limits 'should' depend on $\theta_1$ . On the other hand, as the difference in the upper and lower limits is always $2\pi$, and the integrand is periodic (in $\phi$), the actual integral does not depend on $\theta_1$, and one can take the limits  as given in the solution above.

Comment: This is a great solution, thanks a lot achille! Just cause I'm curious, have you encountered this integral before? Your substitutions are very clever. Also thanks for pointing out a few rough spots peter.

Comment: @UglyMousanova19 I have seen this sort of integral a lot but never really need to evaluate one in 2d. (The 3d version is simpler to evaluate as one can use multipole expansion in terms of Legendre polynomials).